# I have Case handler class and I am new to test classes and I am struck, Could you please help me out on this

Tags: code-coverage

Here is the CaseHandler Class

```
public class CaseHandler {
    public static void onCaseInsertOrUpdate(List<Case> newCases, Map<Id, Case> oldMap){
        List<Id> acctIds = new List<Id>();
        Map<Id, String> acctIdChildNames = new Map<Id, String>();
        for (Case record: newCases) {
            if (record.Household__c != null && (oldMap == null || record.Household__c != oldMap.get(record.Id).Household__c)) {
                acctIds.add(record.Household__c);
            }
        }

        if (acctIds.isEmpty()) {
            return;
        }

        List<Child__c> children = [SELECT Id, Household__c,Child_Name__c, Child_Age__c FROM Child__c WHERE Household__c IN :acctIds];

        for (Child__c child: children) {
            if (acctIdChildNames.containsKey(child.Household__c)) {
                String childName = acctIdChildNames.get(child.Household__c) + '\n' + child.Child_Name__c + '(' + child.Child_Age__c + ')';
                acctIdChildNames.put(child.Household__c, childName);
            } else {
                acctIdChildNames.put(child.Household__c, child.Child_Name__c + '(' + child.Child_Age__c + ')');
            } 
        }

        // No need to write update because we are triggering this on before trigger
        for (Case record: newCases) {
            if (record.Household__c != null) {
                record.Children_Names__c = acctIdChildNames.get(record.Household__c);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the test class

```
@isTest
public class CaseHandlerTest {
    @isTest
    static void caseInsertTest() {
        Account a = new Account(Name='Test');     
        Child__c child = new Child__c(Child_Name__c='Child 1',Child_Age__c=10,Household__c=a.Household_ID__c);
        Case c = new Case(Status='New',Household__c=a.Id);
        Test.startTest();
        insert a;
        insert child;
        insert c;
        Test.stopTest();
        System.debug('Child Name : '+child.Child_Name__c);
        System.debug('Case Id : '+c.Id);
        System.debug('Account Id : '+a.Name);
        c = [SELECT Children_Names__c FROM Case WHERE Id =:c.Id];
        System.debug('Children name and age: ' + c.Children_Names__c);
        System.assertEquals('Child 1 (10)', c.Children_Names__c);
    }    
}
```

But I am getting 41% code coverage could you please help me out on this.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is you try up get `a.Id` before inserting `a`. I recommend you insert each record or collection thereof after construction.

```
Account a = new Account(Name='Test');
Child__c child = new Child__c(Child_Name__c='Child 1',Child_Age__c=10,Household__c=a.Household_ID__c);
Case c = new Case(Status='New',Household__c=a.Id);
// a.Id is still null
Test.startTest();
insert a;
// now a.Id is populated
insert child;
insert c;
```

Instead, insert the record before trying to get its Id.

```
Account a = new Account(...);
insert a;
Case c = new Case(Household__c=a.Id);
```